# Render JSON with sub object using React

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs

Maybe someone there knows, how can I render "department" object from JSON?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "one",
        "department": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "development"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "two",
        "department": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "testing"
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to display the data such that It's my render

```
    render() {
        const title =<h3>Employee</h3>;
        const {Employees, isLoading} = this.state;

        if (isLoading)
            return(<div>Loading....</div>);

        let rows=
            Employees.map( employee =>
                <tr key={employee.id}>
                    <td>{employee.id}</td>
                    <td>{employee.name}</td>
                    <td>{employee.department.name}</td>
                    <td><Button size="sm" color="danger" onClick={() => this.remove(employee.id)}>Delete</Button></td>

                </tr>);

return {rows};
```

**Tanx very much!**

Comment: Not sure what is your issue. You need to provide what u require as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed id! I needed to my back end code modify some... from "department" to private `String departmentName;`

and front

```
 let rows=
        Employees.map( employee =>
            <tr key={employee.id}>
                <td>{employee.id}</td>
                <td>{employee.name}</td>
                <td>{employee.department.departmentName}</td>
                <td><Button size="sm" color="danger" onClick={() => this.remove(employee.id)}>Delete</Button></td>

            </tr>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    render() {
        const title =<h3>Employee</h3>;
        const {Employees, isLoading} = this.state;

        if (isLoading)
            return(<div>Loading....</div>);

        let rows=
            Employees.map( employee => {
                return `<tr key=${employee.id}>
                    <td>${employee.id}</td>
                    <td>${employee.name}</td>
                    <td>${employee.department.name}</td>
                    <td><Button size="sm" color="danger" onClick=${() => this.remove(employee.id)}>Delete</Button></td>

                </tr>` });

return {rows};
```